# How can I display a QRcode on a mesh in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, qr-code

I took the QRcode library from here http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/ and I wanted to display it on a face of an mesh object as a texture using this code:

```
var qrcode = new QRCode( "test", {
    text: "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie",
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    colorDark : "#000000",
    colorLight : "#ffffff",
    correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});
...
var cuboidTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( qrcode );
cuboidTexture.needsUpdate = true;
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null qrcode.min.js:1
```

Is something I'm doing wrongly? Or I just can't have an QRcode as texture?

EDIT:
Using the qrcode.js library the error is the same:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null qrcode.js:359
```

Comment: I know it is not what you asked but QRCode -> 3D: http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_ubiquity_test

Comment: The error comes from qrcode. Can you use `qrcode.js` instead of `qrcode.min.js` to see where the error is comming from

Comment: @gaitat ok, so error aside, since QRCode->3d means I can't use it as a texture to a mesh like this? `var cuboidTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( qrcode );` What should I do to have a face of a mesh displayed as qrcode? [or at least to display the qr-image, loosing the other info such as text]

Comment: No, no, no. My first post meant that you can see your qrcode as 3d, not that what you are doing is wrong. The sample I posted does not use the qrcode library that you are using anyway. So back to your error can you use `qrcode.js` instead of `qrcode.min.js` to see where the error is comming from.

Comment: i replied with the edit of the question

Comment: looking at the error it seems that if you add `<div id="test"></div>` to your js code will take care of it.

Comment: but this way will be added to the <div> and not to the mesh or no?

Comment: This will eliminate the error but should also add it as a texture.

Comment: so, the error is gone, but the qrcode-image is displayed above the the javascript code, where the div is, and not on the mesh. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
var cuboidTexture = new THREE.Texture( test );
cuboidTexture.needsUpdate = true;

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: cuboidTexture } );
```

Comment: this way the cuboidTexture become 'undefined' :`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'needsUpdate' of undefined`

Comment: Can you create a simple jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I gave up, and decided to do this in a easier way: I just put the images of QRcode in a folder and then use them as a normal texture. Thank you anyway for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument ("test") has to be the ID of the DOM-element you want the QR-Code to go.

HTML:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

JS:

```
var qrcode = new QRCode("foo");
```

For the rest, see http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/

PS: the example with the ID "test" is not well documented ;-)